# pandas read_excel keep visualized content as it is

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a big issue that I think is quite hard hence you`re my last hope.

I have excel sheets that have columns with various data types like dates, floats, ints and strings.
They represent test cases so it might always be that the data types will change accordingly.

I want to read the excel sheet so it preserves the data as it's shown when I access it via Excel.

The problem is that pandas read_excel converts floats like `30.00` to -> `30` and creates datetime objects from timestamps `10.10.2020` -> datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 10, 0, 0) which is represented as `2020-10-10 00:00:00` when I convert it to a string.

You see that this is definitely completely different from the input and I just want to keep the data AS IS.

**I don`t seek for answers to change the data format and floats back, but rather how to prevent pandas from using the number format to change the data representation.** I recognized that this already happens with the engine that I use (openpyxl) but wasn`t able to solve the issue with openpyxl as well.

Maybe you can recommend me an other library that works as well.

I have recognized that manually saving an excel sheet as csv has the exact form that I want, but that's not an option. If this process can be automated than this would also be a feasible answer, but I wasn't able to find an approach for this workarount

Here is an example:

Original data (snippet):
[image]

What pandas reads:
[image]

Comment: Kindly share a sample file with expected output

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried messing around wiht `read_excel()` parameters such as `dtype` or `decimal`?

Have a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: Yes I did try that, but dtype can only be specified for columns, which means I can't really use it here. Also if I set dtype=str I still get the same issue, because openpyxl directly converts the dates before the dataframe gets created

Comment: If you read the documentation for the `decimal` parameter you'll see that this also only works for TEXT, but the Excel sheet holds any sorts of data types.

Comment: Ok, I did some tests and I also had troubles with `read_excel()` and `openpyxl`. If your requirement is just to show data as is can't you format all cells of the Excel file to be "text" by manually set it from Excel itself? I'm aware that this makes only sense if you have a limited amount of files to process...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not an option, the excel sheet should be untouched.